# jQuery- walk through YouTube URLs and add options

Tags: youtube, jquery

I have a series of YouTube URLs on the page, that each look like one of these:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XFMjR2SgEP0?list=PLd4hww6QWFS5HMUQzSs3r-90jMRtCiCdi" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DVPP1elkhKU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As you can see, the first tag above has a 'list' parameter at the end of the URL; the second tag has no parameters on the URL.

I need to use jQuery to append a new parameter, `showinfo=0`, to every YouTube URL on the page. And obviously this needs to be preceded with either `?` or `&`, depending on if there are other parameters before it.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existance of a question mark and append appropriately:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', function(idx, src) {
    return src + (src.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'showinfo=0';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) can take a callback function?

```
$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').attr('src', function (i, str) {
    return (str.match(/\?/)) ? str+'&showinfo=0' : str+'?showinfo=0';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6rUaE/